# How does one reformat an SQLite database so that the rowIds equal the placement on the table and when a row is deleted lower rows move up

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, rowid

I have recently come across a point where I need a database to do the above. I have looked online and have not found something that solves the problem and I understood. Another way to phrase the above question is "how could I make the rows always in integer order moving to replace voids filled by deleted rows?" Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why this functionality is required, can you give us some detail?

Comment: Explain why you came "across a point where I need a database to do" this. It may help provider betters answers to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One gets a greater understanding of what SQL is and how to use it within a given implementation to avoid considering questions and approaches that are incorrect and likely to lead to error-ridden, excessive, invalid, unmaintainable, results.
You don't change the primary key.  You add an order column or use rownum(oracle) or something like that.  Leave the rowids / primary key alone.

Comment: Thank you, due to this I created a method to solve this issue. Accepted and an upvote.